# Html Canvas Overlay that don't disable content under

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I want to put the canvas defined by the red border over the div (black border) that is currently under it. It should have the same size as the div. I also want to be able to click on buttons and select text that is under the canvas. 
I have been trying to do this for 2 days now and can't figure it out...

[image]

```
<canvas id="canvas">

</canvas>
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container-fluid" id="canvas-container">
    </div>
</div>
```

current css (I know it's a mess, but I have been trying a lot of things)

```
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {
  /* Margin bottom by footer height */
  margin-bottom: 60px;
  margin-top: 50px; /* Required margin for .navbar-fixed-top. Remove if using .navbar-static-top. Change if height of navigation changes. */
}
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}


/* Custom page CSS
-------------------------------------------------- */
/* Not required for template or sticky footer method. */

body > .container {
  padding: 60px 15px 0;
}
.container .text-muted {
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.footer > .container {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

code {
  font-size: 80%;
}

.jumbotron
{
  text-align: center;
}
#canvas-container
{
  padding: 0;
  //position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.jumbotron
{
    padding: 0;
    #position: absolute;
}

canvas {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: Can you post your css? It looks like there might be a margin or padding issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify:

```
canvas {
  pointer-events:none;
}
```

Here is a js fiddle where you can test clicking on the area where the black box is under the red box:

https://jsfiddle.net/1n1bp7m9/1/